# Server side dynamic XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-controls

I am working on an asp.net project where I have to create on the server side a XML file dynamically. The data comes from the server and I have to sent that to the client as a response to a request. The client (silverlight) gets the response and uses the data to feed a GUI control. Now, I am getting this error and a blank control with no data:

```
906 Content-Length mismatch: Response Header indicated 192,822 bytes, but server sent 192,856 bytes.
```

That basically is telling me that the response is actually larger than what the header says. I checked the response in Fiddler to make sure the XML file is correct and I found some html tags at the end of the XML. Of course it is not being parsed on the client side and the control is totally blank.

Here is the code

```
 ...

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                //Use a writer to greate the XML
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms))
                {
                    writer.WriteStartDocument(); //Header
                    writer.WriteComment("Response");
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("sfdata"); //<Root>
                        {      

                                  writer.WriteStartElement("dataPoint");
                                {                        
                                    writer.WriteStartElement("ids");                                        
                                    foreach (int i in baseIndexes)
                                    {
                                        writer.WriteStartElement("sfId");
                                        writer.WriteValue(i);
                                        writer.WriteEndElement();                                            
                                    }
                                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                                }
                                writer.WriteEndElement(); //<End dataPoint>
                            }
                           writer.WriteEndElement(); //closes <Root>

                       }
                    writer.WriteEndDocument();
                    writer.Close();

                //Convert Memory Stream to Byte Array
                    byte[] data = ms.ToArray();

                    string xmlFileName = "OrdExp_" + DateTime.Today.Year.ToString() +
                        DateTime.Today.Month.ToString("00") +
                        DateTime.Today.Day.ToString("00");

                    //Creating the Context
                    this.Context.Response.Clear();

                    //Heads up browser, here comes some XML
                    this.Context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
                    this.Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition:",
                        "attachment;filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(xmlFileName));

                    //Set the size of the file so the progress bar reports that correctly
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length",
                        data.Length.ToString());

                    this.Context.Response.BinaryWrite(data);                            
                    this.Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
                    ms.Flush();
                    ms.Close();
                }
```

Hopefully I did not miss any parenthesis.

That is all the code to build the file and return it in the Context.Response. I have gone through it multiple times and I do not see anything that would add extra html tags at the end but I am not very good with this stuff. So I may be missing something. These are the tags I am finding at the end of the xml file:

```
</span>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `Context.Response.End()` after the write? It may throw an error, so you may have to handle it, but it should cut off unneeded HTML.

Comment: Why are you sending XML as binary? If its binary why is content type "text/xml"? Should be octet stream.

Comment: Yuriy, yes, I did that and sure enough it was throwing an error, so I changed it to this.Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest() as per Microsoft documentation... I will try changing it back; but if I remember well I think I experienced this with Response.End() as well.

Comment: loopedcode thanks for your comment... simple answer... I did not know a better way... you are welcome to suggest something else. Thanks for your help!